# Arduino driver problem

Tags: 16.10, arduino

I'm new in Ubuntu, and I had a problem. I installed Arduino IDE and everything worked perfectly since I was using my Arduino UNO board. But when I tried to upload my sketch to an Arduino NANO (with CH40 chip), and I got some error. Please help me, if you can.
Thanks.

Comment: Which error did you get? Look for the output of `dmesg`when plugged in the Arduino - might be the serial is not `ttyUSB0`, depending on the driver, but `ttyACM0`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The NANO was connected, and `dmesg` said `ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0` , but when uploading sketch, I got an error message `avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied` . Now what to do? Thanks.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0`will show the protection; usually owner and group is `root dialout`. So you should add your user to the group `dialout`:  `sudo adduser <user> dialout`

Comment: Hello again! When I was typing `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` in, it gave `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 febr  18 17:49 /dev/ttyUSB0` then I tried to add my user to the group, but I couldn't do it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "couldn't do"? No `sudo` rights, what else? Remember you have to log out and in again to get the group membership working!

Comment: Hi! I tried it again and now it works like a charm.  Thanks.